# Polars - how to parallelize lambda that uses only Polars expressions?

Tags: python-polars

This runs on a single core, despite not using (seemingly) any non-Polars stuff. What am I doing wrong?

(the goal is to convert a list in `doc_ids` field in every row into its string representation, s.t. `[1, 2, 3]` (list[int]) -> `'[1, 2, 3]'` (string))

```py
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame(dict(ent = ['a', 'b'], doc_ids = [[2,3], [3]]))
df = (df.lazy()
    .with_column(
        pl.concat_str([
            pl.lit('['),
            pl.col('doc_ids').apply(lambda x: x.cast(pl.Utf8)).arr.join(', '),
            pl.lit(']')
        ])
        .alias('docs_str')
    )
    .drop('doc_ids')
).collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we want to avoid `apply` at all costs.  It acts like a black-box function that Polars cannot optimize, leading to single-threaded performance.

Here's one way that we can eliminate `apply`: replace it with [`arr.eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.list.ExprListNameSpace.eval.html#polars.internals.expr.list.ExprListNameSpace.eval).  `arr.eval` allows us to treat a list as if it were an Expression/Series, which allows us to use standard expressions on it.

```py
(
    df.lazy()
    .with_column(
        pl.concat_str(
            [
                pl.lit("["),
                pl.col("doc_ids")
                .arr.eval(pl.element().cast(pl.Utf8))
                .arr.join(", "),
                pl.lit("]"),
            ]
        ).alias("docs_str")
    )
    .drop("doc_ids")
    .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ ent ┆ docs_str │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ str      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ a   ┆ [2, 3]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ [3]      │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried `eval`, but was missing that `pl.element()` step.